# how to assert equality for one of multiple outcomes on python3 unittest

Tags: python-unittest

I'm trying to build a test for a topological sort where the answer for top_sort(graph) will be either [1,2,3,4,5] or [1,3,2,4,5] and was wondering how to achieve this with unittest. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you make a `list` containing these answers and any other valid ones, and check if what `top_sort` returns is `in` that list. To answer better than that, I think we'd have to see your code / your attempt at the test.

Comment: @Noah thanks! so, `self.assertIn(top_sort(graph), [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,2,4,5]])`?